# Is it possible to parameterise a connection to different Snowflake DBs using OAuth when embedding Tableau?

Tags: parameters, oauth, single-sign-on, tableau-api, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In the case of implementing a multi-tenant solution with Tableau, where you want to embed it using SSO, is it possible to parameterise the Oauth connection to Snowflake?

The idea is that people authenticate via SSO, and are then directed via their particular parameterised Oauth credentials to a specific database in Snowflake so that we don't store different customers' data in the same Snowflake DB.

Or is it the case that once people authenticate via SSO, they all have to use the **same** Oauth authentication into Snowflake?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but you could also leave the database blank in your connection string and then set each user's default namespace to the database that you want them to use.  Is that the business case you are after?

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-user.html

Comment: Many thanks for the idea, Mike. Ideally we'd do this without having seen the user before or anticipating that they would be authing in, but this might be a way to do it.